# ASP.NET app on Apache Mono Ubuntu compiler error as log4net is unable to be found

Tags: apache-2.2, mono

I'm trying to get a vulnerable practice ASP.NET web application ([WebGoat.NET](https://github.com/jerryhoff/WebGoat.NET)) installed on Apache Mono on Ubuntu. I've followed this [guide](http://www.frameloss.org/2012/05/23/installing-webgoat-net-using-apache-on-ubuntu/) and it all went smoothly; however, whenever I try to run the app I get this error:

```
The type or namespace name `log4net' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Log4net.dll is in the lib folder of the application directory. It's also in the /usr/lib/mono/gac directory. I'm not sure where else it needs to be. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put in the `bin/` folder of your web application?

Answer (score 0):

I also followed that [guide](http://www.frameloss.org/2012/05/23/installing-webgoat-net-using-apache-on-ubuntu/) and received the log4net could not be found error. To fix it I followed the steps in the [official readme](https://github.com/jerryhoff/WebGoat.NET/blob/master/README) under the heading **How To Build And Run under Mac OS X and Linux**.

After following [this guide](http://www.frameloss.org/2012/05/23/installing-webgoat-net-using-apache-on-ubuntu/), I did the following as per the readme:

- Installed sqlite3 using: `apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev`
- cd into WebGoat root directory (e.g. `cd /var/www/webgoat-net/`) and run `xbuild`
- Installed xsp4 using: `apt-get install mono-xsp4`
- cd into WebGoat project (e.g. `cd /var/www/webgoat-net/WebGoat/`) and run: `xsp4`
- Open your web browser and go to http://localhost:8080
- if you see WebGoat home page click on 'Set Up Database'
- Fill in the database form:

  **Data Provider**: Sqlite

  **Data File Path**: `/var/www/webgoat-net/sqlite3/webgoat.db`

  **Client Executable**: `/usr/bin/sqlite3`

  and click 'Rebuild Database'.